# sql, get aggregated list instead of looping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

1. tasklists (id, done)
2. tasks (id, tasklist_id, done)

now I want to find all tasklists that have done set to 0 and where all its tasks have done set to 1, so i can set the tasklist to 1 as well.

I know how to do it when I go through each list one by one:

```
SELECT COUNT(done) 
FROM tasks
WHERE done != 1
AND tasklist_id = 13;
```

This checks if all tasks of list 13 are done, but I would like to have it in a way that I get a result that shows all lists that have a count of 0 for above query.

EDIT: DB = mysql

sample data:

tasklists:

```
id, done
1, 0
2, 0
3, 0
4, 1
```

tasks:

```
id, done, tasklist_id
1, 1, 1
2, 0, 1
3, 1, 2
4, 1, 2
5, 1, 3
6, 1, 4
```

expected result:

```
tasklist_id
2
3
```

It should not include 1, because task nr. 2 (belonging to list 1) is not done yet, and it should also not include 4, because the list is already set to done.

Comment: You said: 3 tables, where is the 3rd?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name mysql

Comment: @McNets, sry, should be two

Comment: @jarlh just added sample data to the question

Comment: is there any order, a datetime for example. is task.id an identity field?

Comment: @McNets no, order does not matter. id is the pk (INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: if you want to know if last done=1, order matter

Comment: @McNets It does not have to be the last one. The tasklist should be excluded if ANY of it's tasks is has done = 0. Order would only help with execution speed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists` to make sure there is no unfinished task:

```
select id from tasklists tl where done = 0 and not exists (
    select * from tasks where tasklist_id = tl.id and done = 0
)
```

Also, it maybe a good idea to implement this check via [Update After triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)